# Extract numeric parameters from template

Tags: c++11, template-meta-programming

I have following struct:

```
template <size_t INDEX_SIZE, size_t GENERATION_SIZE>
struct Handle
{
    uint32_t index : INDEX_SIZE;
    uint32_t generation : GENERATION_SIZE;
};
```

In code I declare a lot of type aliases like this:

```
using Object1Handle = Handle<12, 16>;
using Object2Handle = Handle<12, 16>;
...
```

I would like to have possibility to extract INDEX_SIZE and GENERATION_SIZE from alias. It can be macro, meta-template or function. For example:

```
constexpr size_t indexSize = ExtractIndexSize<Object1Handle>::IndexSize;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just add `constexpr size_t IndexSize = INDEX_SIZE;` to `Handle`? Then you can write `Object1Handle::IndexSize`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Because handle structure is crucial for performance. Adding new uint32_t for index and generation will double its size. It is replacement for pointers, so its used in a lot of places in system.

Comment: Make it `static` (I simply forgot that part). It's going to be a compile-time constant, with no effect at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, that is possible. Using specialization:

```
template<class HandleInst>
struct ExtractIndexSize;

template<size_t index_size_, size_t generation_size_>
struct ExtractIndexSize<
  Handle<index_size_, generation_size_>
> {
  static constexpr size_t index_size = index_size_;
  static constexpr size_t generation_size = generation_size_;
};
```

However, in this simple example (as also pointed out in the comments to your question) the `static constexpr size_t` could also be **moved to `Handle`**.

An **alternative** yielding "getter-like" syntax and fewer restrictions is

```
template<class HandleInst>
struct ExtractIndexSize;

template<size_t index_size_, size_t generation_size_>
struct ExtractIndexSize<
  Handle<index_size_, generation_size_>
> {
  static constexpr size_t index_size() { return index_size_; }
  static constexpr size_t generation_size() { return generation_size_; }
};
```